# IIS - Creating a new thread for thread pooling performance

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, threadpool

In my book "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515):Web Applications Development with MS .NET Framework 4, it states:

(The context is IIS 6 and 7)

> Thread pooling can be tricky. When
>   implementing asynchronous handlers and
>   webpages, use a performance testing
>   tool to verify performance under a
>   heavy load. Sometimes the overhead
>   introduced by asynchronous programming
>   can offset the benefits. Whether
>   performance improves depends on many
>   aspects of the application and web
>   server configuration. **One sure way to
>   get performance gains is to create a
>   new thread. There is only one Common
>   Language Runtime (CLR) thread pool per
>   AppDomain, so you must be sure to not
>   just consume the same threads ASP.NET
>   would be using. Instead, create your
>   own.**

How do I create a new thread without reusing the same threads in the current thread pool?